# How can I make a certain section (circular section) of my mesh have different material than the rest?

Tags: modeling

[image]

Hello, I am trying to make the area in red to have a different texture than the rest of the mesh. How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Press K to activate the knife tool and draw where you have the red line going. Then use the material tab to set your material.